# Magento 2.4 User deprecated functionality session id is not used as url

Tags: magento2.4

Hi we are getting this error have set session IDs to no in-store configuration but still get the error. [image: Error messages]

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to come from the Ced_VivaPayments module, which is using the following **deprecated method** (which should obviously not be used anymore) :

```
\Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver::getSid()
```

This come from its Session Manager class : `\Ced\VivaPayments\Session\SessionManager`.

You should contact the Ced Commerce support to fix this issue on their module.